# Redirect to another action with id

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, redirect

In my ASP MVC controller I want to redirect to another controller and action with an *id*:

```
int thisEvent = 20;
return Redirect("event/details/?id=" + thisEvent);
```

It should redirect to **/event/details/?id=200** or **/event/details/20** For some reason it is not working.

I get this error:

> Redirect URI cannot contain newline characters

Comment: `return RedirectToAction("details", "event", new { id = thisEvent }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of concatenating URI you can use `RedirectToAction`, provide controller and action names as well as parameters passed to action and let routing engine create redirection URI for you.

Here I'm supposing from your URI that your controller has name `EventController` and action you're redirecting to has name `Details`:

```
return RedirectToAction("Details", "Event", new { id = thisEvent });
```

Comment: I get a HTTP 400 Bad Request. But the URL exists, since I can visit it manually: event/details/20

Comment: Hmm.... what is result of `Url.Action("Details", "Event", new { id = thisEvent });` under debugger in the same place where you're trying to redirect? Probably it is some typo here in controller/action names.